# Why TextWatcher needed

Tags: android, textwatcher

So, after going through some docs regarding TextWatcher, I'm still not too sure why it's actually needed. Any help with real example (no code) will be great. Thanks.

Comment: what you understood after reading those docs?

Comment: by using textwatcher ,you can customize the edittext like keeping currency symbol as default( $ 1.00) where user cant clear the $ symbol, then you can set the space between numbers( 123-123-1234) in this when user type the numbers , (-)sign automatically occurs for them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextWatcher is needed to know if a field text has been changed.

Presume you have a mobile number, and you need to check the length of it. As a standard mobile number should contain 10 digits. You have an error field at the side which will go away once the edittext length will be greater than 10. How will you know that now the length is greater than 10?

To overcome this we have textwatcher method which watch over the edittext field. Generally we will check length of edittext in AfterTextChanged callback and it will work in realtime. After that you can make your logics behind what to do after the length is greater than 10.

This is just an example. There are certain many more ways in which you can use textwatcher.

Answer (score 0):

**TextWatcher :**

TextWatcher is used to keep watch on the EditText content while user inputs the data. It allows you to keep track on each character when entered on EditText. A Text Watcher is really helpful for scenarios like login/register screen validation.

The `TextWatcher` have Three method is below :

**Method 1 :** [afterTextChanged(Editable s)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable))

=>  This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed.

**Method 2 :** [beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#beforeTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

=>  This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after.

**Method 3 :**  [onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

=>  This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before.